# Compare current array element vs previous array element

Tags: php

I am going through a foreach loop like so:

```
$ticks = $api->candle("APPLUSD", "4h", "10");
foreach($ticks as $tick)
{
    //do something here
}
```

Within each tick I have an open and close value for the candle. I'd like to try and determine if the current array value in my foreach loop open and close value is greater than the previous open and close in the last value that I just processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a temp variable, like "last_tick"?

```
$ticks = $api->candle("APPLUSD", "4h", "10");
$last_tick = null;
foreach($ticks as $tick)
{
    if (!is_null($last_tick)) {
      //do something here
    }
    $last_tick = $tick;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle the first iteration by initializing `$last_open` and `$last_close`

```
$ticks = $api->candle("APPLUSD", "4h", "10");
$last_open = $last_close = // insert largest value

foreach($ticks as $tick)
{
    if (($tick->open > $last_open) && ($tick->close > $last_close)) {
        // do something
    }

    $last_open = $tick->open;
    $last_close = $tick->close;
}
```